# Multi-Auth Auth::user() Showing null Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-authentication

I am implementing multiple authentication as I have 3 different user groups. I am trying the following steps.

**LoginController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use Auth;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesUsers;


    protected $redirectTo = '/home';


    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
        $this->middleware('guest:admin')->except('logout');
        $this->middleware('guest:manager')->except('logout');
        $this->middleware('guest:vendor')->except('logout');
    }

    public function showAdminLoginForm()
    {
        return view('auth.login', ['url' => 'admin']);
    }

    public function adminLogin(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'email'   => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required|min:6'
        ]);

        if (Auth::guard('admin')->attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password], $request->get('remember'))) {

            return redirect()->intended('/admin');
        }
        return back()->withInput($request->only('email', 'remember'));
    }

    public function showManagerLoginForm()
    {
        return view('auth.login', ['url' => 'manager']);
    }

    public function managerLogin(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'email'   => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required|min:6'
        ]);

        if (Auth::guard('manager')->attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password], $request->get('remember'))) {

            return redirect()->intended('/manager');
        }
        return back()->withInput($request->only('email', 'remember'));
    }

    public function showVendorLoginForm()
    {
        return view('auth.login', ['url' => 'vendor']);
    }

    public function vendorLogin(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'email'   => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required|min:6'
        ]);

        if (Auth::guard('vendor')->attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password], $request->get('remember'))) {

            return redirect()->intended('/vendor');
        }
        return back()->withInput($request->only('email', 'remember'));
    }
}
```

**AdminController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use Auth;

class AdminController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest:admin');   
    }

    public function dashboard()
    {
        dd(auth()->user());
        return view('admin');
    }
}
```

**ManagerController** and **VendorController** are same As **AdminController**.

**Web.php**

```
Route::view('/', 'welcome');
Auth::routes();

Route::prefix('admin')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/login', 'Auth\LoginController@showAdminLoginForm');
    Route::post('/login', 'Auth\LoginController@adminLogin');
    Route::get('/register', 'Auth\RegisterController@showAdminRegisterForm');
    Route::post('/register', 'Auth\RegisterController@createAdmin');
});

Route::prefix('manager')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/login', 'Auth\LoginController@showManagerLoginForm');
    Route::post('/login', 'Auth\LoginController@managerLogin');
    Route::get('/register', 'Auth\RegisterController@showManagerRegisterForm');
    Route::post('/register', 'Auth\RegisterController@createManager');
});

Route::prefix('vendor')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/login', 'Auth\LoginController@showVendorLoginForm');
    Route::post('/login', 'Auth\LoginController@vendorLogin');
    Route::get('/register', 'Auth\RegisterController@showVendorRegisterForm');
    Route::post('/register', 'Auth\RegisterController@createVendor');
});


Route::view('/home', 'home')->middleware('auth');

Route::get('/admin', 'AdminController@dashboard');
Route::get('/manager', 'ManagerController@dashboard');
Route::get('/vendor', 'VendorController@dashboard');
```

**RedirectIfAuthenticated.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class RedirectIfAuthenticated
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if ($guard == "admin" && Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
                return redirect('/admin');
        }
        if ($guard == "manager" && Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            return redirect('/manager');
        }
        if ($guard == "vendor" && Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            return redirect('/vendor');
        }
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            return redirect('/home');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

**config.auth.php**

```
<?php

return [

    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'admin',
        'passwords' => 'admins',
    ],


    'guards' => [

        'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'admins',
        ],

        'manager' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'managers',
        ],

        'vendor' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'vendors',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
    ],

    'providers' => [

        'admins' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Admin::class,
        ],

        'managers' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Manager::class,
        ],


        'vendors' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Vendor::class,
        ],
    ],

    'passwords' => [
        'admins' => [
            'provider' => 'admins',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
        'managers' => [
            'provider' => 'managers',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
        'vendors' => [
            'provider' => 'vendors',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
    ],

];
```

When I am trying to get the Auth::user() by doing dd() at AdminController, it shows me null because of multi-auth. Though it logged in successfully. I assume I am not using proper guard for the admin. But at the same time I have no clue how to fix this. Please help me out.

Comment: In your models, did you use `class Admin extends Authenticatable` or did you extend the `Model` class?

Answer (score 1):

In multi authentications:
We can access authenticated user directly using Auth::user(). It will return the authentication by default guard = 'users'.
For other authentication, we should user guard('guard_name').
In your case, you should use Auth::guard('admins')->user() instead of Auth::user().

Answer (score 0):

Everything seems alright. But you have missed adding **web middleware** for routes.

Please edit your **web.php** like this and it will work.

```
 Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
     // all your routes use Auth() besides login route should be encapsulated and go inside this.
 });
```

> it is because web middleware has session class, check-in app.Http/kernel.php

```
\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
```